# argv[] saves my input only up to the 9. input

Tags: c, cs50, argv

So im trying to code a problemset from cs50, in which i have to convert a message into a secret message with all the letters mixed up.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string key = argv[1];

    int werte_key[sizeof key];

    for (int i= 0; i<sizeof key; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", key[i]);
    }
    //checks ob alle Vorraussetzungen erfüllt sind:

    //Wenn der eingegebene key nicht 26 Stellen lang ist:
    if (sizeof key != 26)
    {
        printf("%i\n", (int) sizeof key);
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

sadly my code messes up instantly. My input is ./substitution ACBEDGFIHKJMLONQPSRUTWVZXY but when i let the code print`your text` out my input via

```
for (int i= 0; i<sizeof key; i++)
{
    printf("%c\n", key[i]);
}
```

i get A C B E D G F I 8 and after that the error message "Key must contain 26 characters.".
As you can probably tell im a beginner and im completely clueless as to why thats happening or what to search for in the internet to fix this problem.

I am sorry for my poor english as it is not my first language and thank you for everyone helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof key` key is wrong. That gives the number of bytes in the `key` object. The `key` object is not your string; it is a pointer to the first character of a string. Its type is `char *`. Its size in your C implementation is eight bytes.

To get the length of a string, use the `strlen` function, which is declared in the standard header `<string.h>`.

Comment: perfect works as intended thank you

Comment: @Lxqnd If you found the answer helpful, then accept and upvote this guy's answer as gratitude. Here, I'll do it for you.

Comment: @Lxqnd: In case you don't understand this answer because you don't know what a "pointer" is, don't worry about it for now. You will learn it in week 4 of CS50.

Comment: Im pretty new to stackoverflow and i cant upvote the answer because i need 15 reputation to do so. Didn't see the "accept answer" button but now i did. Thank you for all the help